# How to tweak so that my command works in awk for printf

Tags: awk

I have this command which works in unix to grep top 10 big files.  However, I'm having issue using the command in my Perl script.  Though  the error shows me where I goes wrong but I have no idea to fix it as I'm not familiar with awk.  Can anyone show me how to tweak the command so that I have use it with the backtick in Perl script?
Unix command to grep top 10 file:-

```
find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '%s %u %p\n' \
 | sort -nr \
 | head \
 | awk '{printf"%5.2f MB %s %s\n", $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}'
```

This is how I use in Perl but it show me errors:-

```
my $cmd = `find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '\%s \%u \%p\n' | sort -nr | head | awk '{printf \%9.2f MB \%s \%s\n , \$1\/1024\/1024, \$2, \$3}'` ;
```

Errors shown on execution:-

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %9.2f MB %s %s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:  ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:                ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %9.2f MB %s %s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:  ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:                ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf %9.2f MB %s %s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:  ^ parse error
awk: cmd. line:2:  , $1/1024/1024, $2, $3}
awk: cmd. line:2:                ^ parse error
```

Pls shed some lights on.  Thanks!

Comment: You should use Perl's `File::Find` and let Perl do the parsing of the results. There's no need for `head` or `sort` or `awk` - Perl can do all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the first argument for `printf` in double quotes, like this:
`awk '{printf \"\%9.2f MB \%s \%s\n\", \$1\/1024\/1024, \$2, \$3}'`
(I'm guessing that you should escape quotes too, but I have barely no knowledge of `perl`, so please check this).

Anyway you probably shouldn't shell out, if you have all necessary "native" tools in perl.

Comment: hi Nya, I did this as you suggested --> my $cmd = `find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '\%s \%u \%p\n' | sort -nr | head | awk '{printf \"\%9.2f MB \%s \%s\n\", \$1\/1024\/1024, \$2, \$3}'` ;  but it give me error on the quote" (awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%9.2f MB %s %s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated string).

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know why you would want to use sort head awk within perl, 
however freedom as beer, so here is a example to call awk from within perl :-)

```
my $cmd = qx(find . -name .snapshot -prune -o -printf '\%s \%u \%p\n' | sort -nr | head | awk '{printf("%9.2f MB %s %s \\n",(\$1/1024/1024) ,\$2,\$3);}' );
foreach my $line (split /[\r\n]+/, $cmd) {
 print $line;
}
```

The awk bit, would be equlavant in perl by something like this

```
while (<>) {
    ($Fld1,$Fld2,$Fld3) = split(' ', $_, -1);
    printf "%9.2f MB %s %s\n", ($Fld1 / 1024 / 1024), $Fld2, $Fld3;
}
```